# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+}{ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin x}$

Tags: limits

I want to investigate the value of $\lim_\limits{x \to 0+}{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin x}$. Since the expontial tends really fast to infinity but the sine quite slowly to 0 in comparison I believe the limit to be infinity. But I cannot find I way to prove it. I tried rewriting using the standard limit $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as $\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot xe^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ but I still get an indeterminate form "$1 \cdot 0 \cdot \infty$".

Comment: Are you allowed to use (pieces of) series expansions?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact  that for $t\gt 0$ we have $e^t\gt 1+t\gt t$.

One can prove that $e^t\gt  1+t$ for positive $t$ by considering the function $f(t)=e^t-(1+t)$. We have $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is increasing, because $f'(t)=e^t-1\gt 0$ if $t\gt 0$.

In particular, if $x$ is positive then $xe^{1/x^2}\gt \frac{x}{x^2}$.